# Why does rspec puppet fail with undefined method error when switching ruby versions?

Tags: ruby, rspec, puppet, rspec-puppet

I developed my puppet module with ruby version `1.8.7` ran `bundle install` on the following gem file and rspec tests worked successfully (so did the puppet run):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

if puppetversion = ENV['PUPPET_GEM_VERSION']
  gem 'puppet', puppetversion, :require => false
else
  gem 'puppet', '3.7.5'
end

gem 'metadata-json-lint'
gem 'puppetlabs_spec_helper', '>= 0.1.0'
gem 'puppet-lint', '>= 1.0.0'
gem 'facter', '>= 1.7.0'
gem 'rspec-puppet-facts'

# rspec must be v2 for ruby 1.8.7
if RUBY_VERSION >= '1.8.7' and RUBY_VERSION < '1.9'
  gem 'rspec', '~> 2.0'
end
```

However when I did a `bundle install` on the same `Gemfile` on my CI server which has ruby `1.9.3` I encountered the following rspec failures:

[See verbose errors here](http://pastebin.com/Bt4tgzuf)

**The common erorr is:**

```
Puppet::Error:
       Failed to parse template silex/var/config/settings.json.erb:
         Filepath: /var/tmp/silex/spec/fixtures/modules/silex/templates/var/config/settings.json.erb
         Line: 4
         Detail: undefined method `each_with_index' for "default":String
```

**Template that uses the `each_with_index` method:**

```
{
    "elasticsearch.settings": {
        "connections": [
        <% @elastic_hosts.each_with_index do |host,i| -%>
        {"host":"<%= host['ip'] %>", "port": <%= host['port'] %> }<%= ',' if i < (@elastic_hosts.size - 1) -%>
        <% end -%>
        ],
        "index": "<%= @elastic_index %>"
    }
    },
    "cache.lifetime": <%= @elastic_cache_lifetime %>,
    "environment": "dev",
    "trusted": [
        <% @trusted_hosts.each_with_index do |host,i| -%>
        {"host":"<%= host['host'] %>"}<%= ',' if i < (@trusted_hosts.size - 1) -%>
        <% end -%>
    ],
    "homepage.settings": {
      "hero.count": 20,
      "list.count": 20
    }
}
```

I'm failing to understand why this would fail with a different version of ruby? I've also tried ruby `2.1.1` with the same result. The results are only successful on the CI server with ruby `1.8.7` (same version I used for development of the module).

**UPDATE 1**

It appears that because `elastic_hosts` is a hash map and I had a string it was failing. I did fix this along with `trusted_hosts` (another hash map) which has resulted in most of the tests passing but the error persists.

[See errors here](http://pastebin.com/Ee16xi0j)

**NOTE**: The error is unchanged from the common error highlighted above.

I have also updated the template file above with the full contents.

[My config spec file](http://pastebin.com/xTyN3vpe)

If you look at my config spec file I am not specifying `default` as a string anywhere yet it tells me that it is the error..

**FIX**

As suspected my init spec class had defaults set and adding the hiera look ups for `elastic_hosts` and `trusted_hosts` fixed the issue.

**UPDATE 2**

This behaviour is reproducible between version `1.8.7` and version > `1.9.3`. It seems to have something to with how hashes are treated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple: Because the the `each` method was removed from newer versions of Ruby. One reason was that the method was confusing in the context of `UTF-8` strings: does `each` iterate over *each char* or *each byte*?

But there is `each_char` and you can combine that with `with_index`:

```
string.each_char.with_index do |char, i|
  # ...
end
```

Furthermore you call that method on `@elastic_hosts` what in the snippet clearly should be an array of `hosts`. But the error message tells us that the `@elastic_hosts` is the string `default`. So it makes sense that the method call with `each_with_index` fails, but it seems like the iteration itself does not make sense. I advise to check if `@elastic_hosts` is set correctly.

Comment: `elastic_hosts` is actually a hash map. You are right about it being set to a string. I am working on getting the hiera lookup working. Will update the answer soon.